# Azure mysql Username Without @

Tags: mysql, azure, credentials

I have a remote device that must login to mySQL database, but will not permit special characters on the username field.

When I create a new username, it appends @databasename.

So for example if I create a user called testconnection, it wont work by itself, I must use testconnection@databasename as username.

How can I create a username that is not automatically appended the database name?

Comment: IS this a mysql server or Azure sql DB?

Answer (score 0):

This is MySQL principle, you could fin the principle in the official document:[Adding User Accounts](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/adding-users.html). The `@` is used to specify your host.

It's not the azure mysql appends @hostname, actually it's `%`, account uses the `%` wildcard for the host part, so it can be used to connect from any host.

And if you create with like this code without hostname:

```
CREATE USER 'new_master_user' IDENTIFIED BY 'StrongPassword!';
```

it will append `%`.I add an user with `%` to make the error happens.
[image]

And in MySQL workbench you could find if you set the `Limit to Hosts Matching` null, it will prompt Host name must not be blank. So the hostname is a required parameter.

[image]